# Firebase - FetchError - wrong openssl version number - FetchError: request to /$rpc/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/BatchGetDocuments failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test suite with jest for my firebase admin
functions, using the firebase emulator, and I'm getting this very odd error:

`FetchError: request to https://localhost:8080/$rpc/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/BatchGetDocuments failed, reason: write EPROTO 4388406656:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:`

The error message is actually quite huge and I cant scroll to the bottom of it... I've added a screenshot at the bottom.

Kind of stuck... Thank you for your help

package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "firestore": "firebase emulators:start",
    "jest": "jest --watch",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.1.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
  }
}
```

.env.test

```bash
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
```

firebaseAdmin.test.js

```js
   import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
   import admin from "firebase-admin";
   import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

   // https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/1999#issuecomment-302244429
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
     admin.initializeApp(serviceAccount),
    });
  }

  const app = admin.apps[0];
  const auth = getAuth();
  const db = getFirestore();

  it("should get from the the database", async () => {
  
    const tokenDocRef = db
      .collection(`collection/path`)
      .doc("sessionToken");
  
    const result = await tokenDocRef.get();
    console.log(result.data());

    expect( result).toBeDefined();

  });
```

[image: Huge Error]

Comment: can you try to change in your .env.test and yarn run dev again

`FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://localhost:8080
`

Comment: Thank you @ChristianPaulAndaya, In that case i get the error "Value for argument "FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST" is not a valid host." (also tried with https)